# How to make GCC debug dumps with Makefile projects?

Tags: debugging, gcc, makefile

The title says it pretty nicely. I have a huge project that uses Makefile. How do I do a project-wide debug dumps (say, -fdump-tree-gimple) with GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass `-fdump-tree-gimple` (actually put any pass-name instead of `gimple`, or even `all` to dump all tree passes) to compilation string for every compiler execution (i.e. every time, you are calling gcc on source files or with `-c` option). Dump in form `filename.c.XXX.gimple` for any source file name will appear (XXX is a pass number like 003, depends on gcc version) in a working directory (often it is build folder). Also you may want to specify `-dumpdir` to collect all dumps in a single dump directory, this may be handy to avoid mess.

How will you do it in you makefile -- up to you. You may add it to `$CFLAGS` (most common solution, because dumping **is** a part of compilation flags), or create special variable and pass it around, or hard-code it inside makefile.

If you are building your project with lto, you must pass those flag(s) also on second link stage (i.e. add to LDFLAGS or so).

Comment: Thanks! It's been so long since I've done anything with Makefiles, I have forgot almost everything. :)